# Camera activity returning null android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am building an application where I want to capture an image by the default camera activity and return back to my activity and load that image in a ImageView. The problem is camera activity always returning null. In my `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` method I am getting data as `null`. Here is my code:

```
public class CameraCapture extends Activity {

    protected boolean _taken = true;
    File sdImageMainDirectory;
    Uri outputFileUri;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
            setContentView(R.layout.cameracapturedimage);
                    File root = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "myDir" + File.separator);
                    root.mkdirs();
                    sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName");



                startCameraActivity();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    protected void startCameraActivity() {

        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
        {
            if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                try{
                ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cameraImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

     @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CameraCapture.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            _taken = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(CameraCapture.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: is the sdcard mounted? where u able to see the image 'myPicName'? and do u have the permissions in the manifest?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I can see the file in the ddms while usb debugging. And i also have given the permission. If i use outputFileUri instead of data when loading the image in the imageview it works. That means camera is capturing the image but why i am getting null in the data parameter of onactivityresult() method

Comment: Pay attention if you have allowed the permission to access your Storage.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You are getting wrong because you are doing it wrong way.

If you pass the extra parameter `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` with the camera intent then camera activity will write the captured image to that path and it will not return the bitmap in the `onActivityResult` method.

If you will check the path which you are passing then you will know that actually camera had write the captured file in that path.

For further information you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042695/how-to-get-camera-result-as-a-uri-in-data-folder/10229228#10229228), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230046/630668) and [this](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/04/save-captured-image-to-applications.html)

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the `Intent` would come back `null` if you specify the URI to save to. You should still be able to access the `Intent` and grab the photo's URI from it, etc.

Comment: Just like you said, specifying an URI will cause the thumbnail to become unavaible in OnActivityResult. However if you need both high res and low res in your app, you can follow [this](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=590)

Comment: You can pass the extra paramater `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` with the camera intent, but you have to save the fileUri as a member variable so then it can later be accessed in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: in `onActivityResult()` `data.getData()` supposed to return the uri of the image being saved. RIGHT!

Comment: all of this is horribly documented.  The Android docs sample app doesn't work. http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html produces the same error that the OP is talking about.

Comment: Such a simple thing requires such a complicated actions, that's what is really bad in android development.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be the only valid answer STILL in late 2015! passing EXTRA_OUTPUT and saving the generated file path in a String attribute

Comment: pheeeew... saved my ass big time. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I am doing it another way. The data.getData() field is not guaranteed to return a Uri, so I am checking if it's null or not, if it is then the image is in extras. So the code would be -

```
if(data.getData()==null){
    bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
}else{
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
}
```

I am using this code in the production application, and it's working.

Comment: If `data` is null, how you can call `getData()`?

Comment: data is an intent which is always not-null. The Uri part of the intent object is not guranteed to have a not null value. So if the uri is null we can get the bitmap from the getExtras() method instead and if it's not, then use the Uri to get the file.

Comment: Oh this "data" key returned the Bitmap while i need Uri path. Okay, I can get `Uri from image` through these codes : `public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }`

Comment: Notice, that by using data.getExtras().get("data") you will NOT GET the full sized Bitmap! It's gonna be a thumbnail. It seem to be pretty ugly in a production app...

Comment: i have same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595914/onactivityresult-returning-intent-data-getdata-always-null-only-in-marshmallo/39596066#comment66503271_39596066

Comment: how `data.getExtras.get("data")` can return path if we dont send any putExtra to Intent?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.  I had commented out some lines in my manifest file which caused the thumbnail data to be returned as null.

You require the following to get this to work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I hope this resolves your issue

If you phone is a Samsung, it could be related to this http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/

There is another [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031374/photo-capture-intent-causes-nullpointerexception-on-samsung-phones-only) which may give additional information

Comment: I have the same problem and those permissions doesn't change anything I'm afraid. At least not for me, it seems there is no solution. I've searched for days, how come it is like this? I'm extremely frustrated that I can't take a single picture with an app.

Comment: @cubsink was it a Samsung...?

Comment: Sorry for the late respone @Merlin. But yes it was a samsung device. It was over a year ago, I guess things have changed now.

Comment: @cubsink, ach it was only a year or so ;)

Comment: OP is using Camera Intent, not using camera hardware in his/her own app. So these permissions are actually not required.(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE might require, but not the other ones). Mentioned in the android docs

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest

Note this line - Note: If you are using the camera via an intent, your application does not need to request this permission.

Comment: saved my time!!

Answer (score 4):

*If you are using an ImageView to display the Bitmap returned by Camera Intent
you need to save the imageview reference inside onSaveInstanceState and also restore it later on inside onRestoreInstanceState. Check out the code for onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState below.*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void startCamera(View v) throws IOException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = null;

        photoFile = createImageFile();
        //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            System.out.println(imageBitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ".jpg", /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

    private void setPic() {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        System.out.println(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

after many search :

```
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST = 1;
private ImageView mImageView;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private File photoFile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saisir_frais);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}





@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // set the dimensions of the image
            int targetW =100;
            int targetH = 100;

            // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

           // stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions); i have facing Null value for photoFile parameter, do you know why?, i' testing android Api-23, Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

*Try following code*

```
            {
                final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
                Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
                imageCursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                    if (fullPath.contains("DCIM")) {

                        //get bitmap from fullpath here.
                        return;
                    }
                }
                while (imageCursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 1):

While taking from camera few mobiles would return null. The below workaround will solve. Make sure to check data is null:

```
          private int  CAMERA_NEW = 2;
          private String imgPath;

          private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
               startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_NEW);
          }

         // to get the file path 
         private  Uri setImageUri() {
           // Store image in dcim
              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
              Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
              this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
              return imgUri;
           }
          
          @Override
          public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
          {
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_NEW) {

              try {
                 Log.i("Crash","CAMERA_NEW");
                 if(data!=null &&(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")!=null){
                     bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                     personImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                     Utils.saveImage(bitmap, getActivity());
                               
                 }else{
                       File f= new File(imgPath);
                       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                       options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                       options.inSampleSize= 4;
                       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
                       personImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                              
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate bitmap from the file that you send to camera intent. Please use this code...

```
@Override

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch (requestCode) {

    case CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
     {
        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
           {

                int orientation = getOrientationFromExif(sdImageMainDirectory);// get orientation that image taken

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                InputStream is = null;
                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                m.postRotate(orientation);//rotate image

                is = new FileInputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);

                options.inSampleSize = 4 //(original_image_size/4);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                        bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);

                 // set bitmap to image view    

                 //bitmap.recycle();    
           }

        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }

}

private int getOrientationFromExif(String imagePath) {
        int orientation = -1;
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (exifOrientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    orientation = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    orientation = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    orientation = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    orientation = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to get image exif orientation", e);
        }
        return orientation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File cameraFile = null;

public void openChooser() {
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cameraFile));

    String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"; // Or get from strings.xml
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,new Intent[]{takePhotoIntent});
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                if (selectedImage != null) {
                    //from gallery 
                } else if (cameraFile != null) {
                    //from camera
                    Uri cameraPictureUri = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial. It works for me and use permission as usual in manifesto & also 
check permission

https://androidkennel.org/android-camera-access-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of vigorous research I finally reached to a conclusion.
For doing this, you should save the image captured to the external storage.
And then,retrieve while uploading.
This way the image res doesnt degrade and you dont get NullPointerException too!
I have used timestamp to name the file so we get a unique filename everytime.

```
 private void fileChooser2() {
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String pictureName=getPictureName();
    fi=pictureName;
    File imageFile=new File(pictureDirectory,pictureName);
    Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2);
}
```

Function to create a file name :

```
private String getPictureName() {
    SimpleDateFormat adf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String timestamp = adf.format(new Date());
    return "The New image"+timestamp+".jpg";//give a unique string so that the imagename cant be overlapped with other apps'image formats
}
```

and the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         
        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2 && resultCode==RESULT_OK )//&& data!=null && data.getData()!=null)
        {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            progressDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                File picDir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File imageFile=new File(picDir.getAbsoluteFile(),fi);
            filePath=Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            try {
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/2");
            riversRef.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                        }
                    });
```

Edit: give permissions for camera and to write and read from storage in your manifest.