# android application crash only in samsung device while getting image from camera

Tags: android, camera, imageview

In my application i am getting image from camera. this code completely work on most devices but when i test in sumsung galaxy grand quattro   application crashed.

Here is my Try:

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    try {

        resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 200, 200, true);
        final_image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 200, 200, true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed To Load ", 5000).show();
    }

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(getApplicationContext(), resized);
        BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), blurredBitmap);
        ll.setBackground(ob);

    } else {
        Bitmap blur = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blurback);
        BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), blur);
        ll.setBackground(ob);
    }
    try {
        Bitmap circleimg = getCircularBitmapWithWhiteBorder(resized, 2);
        iv.setImageBitmap(circleimg);
        final_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        imgpath = encodedImageString;
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

**Note :**

```
I tasted my app in
```

1. Micromax Canvas Knight - kitkat
2. Sony Xperia c3 - lollipop
3. Micromax Canvas 2- jellybean

Above device in complite work

1. Samsung galaxy grand quattro - jellybean (Application Crashed)

LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.camera/com.example.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/50298 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.camera/com.example.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2643)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2671)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/50298 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.camera/com.example.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3209)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2630)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:490)
    at com.example.camera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:93)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: @MuhammadBabar you can see logcat

Comment: See this question -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982184/camera-activity-returning-null-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your crash is that data is null. This happens on some devices, instead use the content provider. The data will contain the path you can read out:

```
Bitmap photo;
if(data.getData() == null) {
    photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
} else {
    photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
}
```

That should work for you.

Comment: for me it reverse only samsung(4.4.4) working not in other like sony(5.0), motorola(4.4.4 and 5.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but can help to isolate the problem.

Open the native camera app, select a lower resolution, 2Mpx eg, now, open your app and test it.

I use Cordova, and I realize the App crash when the native camera app has highest resolutions.

Could be a memory issue in the moment that try to resize the image, because it needs open in memory or the need a big cache space in the main storage and there is not space available.