# Can't get camera code from Android docs to work

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I am using code from http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Code:

```
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = FileUtilities.createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); //error
            //code after this doesn't get executed
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get access to the thumbnail and the picture being stored on the device. But for some reason when I try the code, I get a null pointer exception on the data.getExtras(); part.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hope you have declared all the permissions you need for this in manifest.
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="true" />

Comment: I have included those, yes

Comment: which things are given when you use breakpoint at `data.getExtras()`?

Comment: It's a null pointer exception so I imagine it's null (I'm not near the laptop at the moment to verify)

Comment: @SeanHill // that might be 4th case in my answer. so you need to check `if(data == null)`

Comment: @SeanHill, please check my answer and try that once please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one of notorious Android development experience.

Android Intent does not guarantee to give captured image in `data.getExtras()`, especially user utilize 3rd party camera/imaging app. You can find many trials and suggestions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6982184/361100) and anywhere googled with "android camera intent null".

Some common of them are as below.

1. `data.getExtras().get("data");`
2. `data.getExtras()` with different key (i.e "photo")
3. `data.getData()`
4. `Uri.fromFile(f)` for `EXTRA_OUTPUT` predefined path.
5. `Uri.fromFile(f)` with some random filename (datetime format or IMG-xxx) *without* maintaining `EXTRA_OUTPUT` definition.

I recommend you to find it using breakpoint which route of the variable that the intent given. It would be good to check all of them in `if-else if-else` approach.

In addition, check out crash report carefully after releasing the app. You may get the error out of the above trials.

Comment: Huh? Are you implying it's random / inconsistent?

Comment: @SeanHill // what I say _random_ means their (3rd party camera app) unpredictably defined filename.

Comment: I'm just trying to use the default camera

Comment: @SeanHill // what you mean default is not actually default unless it is Nexus. Almost all android vendors like Samsung or Sony make their own camera app as default but it _may or may not_ give same result as document.

Comment: So what do most developers do if there are so many cameras with unreliable or unpredictable behavior?

Comment: @SeanHill // well, like me, read crash report, sigh, fix it, and release.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ThumbNail, you don't need to create a file etc. please try this code below.

```
   Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
```

and to get the results.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imgView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }

    }
```

imgView is the ImageView you want to set the ThumbNail to.

In case if you want to create a file and then try this, [ which is not needed for a Thumbnail], you may want to try adding the following permission to manifest as you are trying to read and write to storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

All the best.

Comment: I have the permissions already. I can get the thumbnail using the simpler version of the code, but not the thumbnail and full image with the file code