# onActivityResult returning Intent data.getData(); always Null Only in Marshmallow and Lollipop

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

Read My Whole Code. It is working perfectly on every Phone except `Marshmallow` and `Lollipop`. In `Marshmallow` and `Lollipop` phones Only problem is coming in `data.getData()` returning `null` only in case of **Picture Captured**. It is working fine if i capture **Video** .I have 4 cases -

1. Choosing Picture from Gallery and show its thumbnail in `Imageview` - Working Fine.
2. Capturing Picture from Camera and show its thumbnail in `Imageview` - **NOT WORKING** in `Marshmallow` and `Lollipop`.
3. Choosing Video from Gallery and show its thumbnail in `Imageview` - Working Fine.
4. 3.Capturing Video from Camera and show its thumbnail in `Imageview` - Working Fine.

Now There are many solutions but neither of them looks satisfactory,If code is working fine in case of Video Capturing then why its NOT working for Image Capturing?Is it a Bug or I am doing wrong somewhere?

Here is My Code . I have commented a line where crash happens-

```
 @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      int THUMBSIZE = 120;
      switch (requestCode){


        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:


            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String column_Name= MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                String picturePath=getPath(column_Name,data.getData());
                Bitmap orientedBitmap = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(picturePath, BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Drawable fullpic=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(orientedBitmap, THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE));
                thumbnailview.setBackground(fullpic);
                editText.setText(picturePath);
                picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                thumbnailview.setClickable(false);

            }
            break;

        case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:

            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String picturePath="";
                String column_Name=MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;

                picturePath=getPath(column_Name,data.getData());

                    //My app Crashes here because in Marshmallow data.getData() is always null.

                Bitmap orientedBitmap = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(picturePath, BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Drawable fullpic=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(orientedBitmap, THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE));
                thumbnailview.setBackground(fullpic);
                editText.setText(picturePath);
                picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                thumbnailview.setClickable(false);


            }
            break;

        case RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO:

            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String column_Name=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
                String videoPath=getPath(column_Name,data.getData());
                Drawable fullpic=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND));
                thumbnailview.setBackground(fullpic);
                editText.setText(videoPath);
                picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                thumbnailview.setClickable(false);


            }
            break;

        case REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE:

            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String column_Name=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
                String videoPath=getPath(column_Name,data.getData());
                Drawable fullpic=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND));
                thumbnailview.setBackground(fullpic);
                editText.setText(videoPath);
                picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                thumbnailview.setClickable(false);


            }
            break;
    }

    if (picker != null) {
        picker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OpenDialog();
            }
        });
    }

}


private String getPath(String column_Name,Uri uri){

    String[] projection = {column_Name};
    String path = "";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index_data ;
    if (cursor != null) {
        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column_Name);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        cursor.close();
    }

    return path;
}

private void OpenDialog(){
    dialogBox.setTitle("Select an Action");
    dialogBox.setMessage("Choose Picture or Video");

    dialogBox.setPositiveButton("Picture", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (check_Permissions()){
                OpenCameraDialog();
            }
            else {
                request_Permissions();
                CAMERA_DIALOG_PERMISSION=1;

            }
        }
    });

    dialogBox.setNegativeButton("Video", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (check_Permissions()){
                OpenVideoDialog();
            }
            else {
                request_Permissions();
                VIDEO_DIALOG_PERMISSION=1;
            }

        }
    });

    dialogBox.show();

}



private void OpenCameraDialog(){

    dialogBox.setTitle("Select an Action");
    dialogBox.setMessage("Choose Picture From");

    dialogBox.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final Intent galleryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryintent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    dialogBox.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            final Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        }
    });

    dialogBox.show();

}

private void OpenVideoDialog(){

    dialogBox.setTitle("Select an Action");
    dialogBox.setMessage("Choose Video From");

    dialogBox.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final Intent galleryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryintent, RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO);
        }
    });

    dialogBox.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            final Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    });
    dialogBox.show();

}

private boolean check_Permissions(){

    boolean GRANTED;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) +
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) +
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) +
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        GRANTED=false;

    }
    else {
        GRANTED=true;
    }
    return GRANTED;
}

private void request_Permissions(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            REQUEST_FOR_PERMISSION);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){

        case REQUEST_FOR_PERMISSION:

            if ((grantResults.length>0)&& (grantResults[0] +grantResults[1]+grantResults[2]+grantResults[3]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){

                if (CAMERA_DIALOG_PERMISSION==1){
                    OpenCameraDialog();
                    CAMERA_DIALOG_PERMISSION=0;
                }
                else if (VIDEO_DIALOG_PERMISSION==1){
                    OpenVideoDialog();
                    VIDEO_DIALOG_PERMISSION=0;
                }

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please GRANT Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As,suggested by @CommonsWare -

> Camera App do not need to return uri.

Also,

> You need to tell Camera app where to write image.

So, i replaced my code with-

```
 final Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            pictureUri=getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

and in `onActivityResult` -

```
 case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:

            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String picturePath="";
                String column_Name= MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                if (data!=null){
                if (data.getData()!=null){
                picturePath=getPathfromUri(column_Name,data.getData());}

                else {
                    picturePath= pictureUri.getPath();

                }
                }
                else {
                    picturePath= pictureUri.getPath();

                }}
```

Answer (score 7):

When we will capture the image from Camera in android then `Uri` or `data.getdata()` comes null. we have two solutions to resolve this issue.

1. We can got the Uri path from the Bitmap Image
2. We can got the Uri path from cursor.

I will implement all methods here, Please carefully watch and read these:-

First i will tell how to get Uri from Bitmap Image:
Complete code is :

First we will capture image through Intent that will same for both methods so this code i will write one time only here :

```
 // Capture Image
        captureImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, reqcode);
                }

            }
        });
```

Now we will Implement OnActivityResult :-(This will be same for both above 2 methods):-

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(requestCode==reqcode && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {

Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

            \\ Show Uri path based on Image
            Toast.makeText(LiveImage.this,"Here "+ tempUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           \\ Show Uri path based on Cursor Content Resolver
            Toast.makeText(this, "Real path for URI : "+getRealPathFromURI(tempUri), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed To Capture Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

\now we will create all above method to create Uri from Image and Cursor methods via classes:

Now  URI path from Bitmap Image

```
  private Uri getImageUri(Context applicationContext, Bitmap photo) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(LiveImage.this.getContentResolver(), photo, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

\ Uri from Real path of saved image

```
  public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
```

Dear Friend copy and paste this code and then try to understood.
I'm 100 % sure this will better for you if you are making corporate Apps.

Answer (score 2):

> It is working perfectly on every Phone except Marshmallow and Lollipop

No, it is not. It will fail on lots of Android versions, when the user chooses a well-written camera app to handle your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request.

Your problem lies here:

```
            if (data.getData()!=null){
            picturePath=getPath(column_Name,data.getData());}
            else {
                //My app Crashes here because in Marshmallow data.getData() is always null.
            }
```

There are at least two flaws here.

The big one is assuming that you get a `Uri` back from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. [That is not documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), and camera apps do not need to return a `Uri`. In particular, in your structure, you will only get a thumbnail back, via `getExtra("data")`. If you want a full-size image, use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on your `Intent`, in which case you know where the image is being stored — it is wherever you are indicating in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

The other one is that you assume that the `Uri` that you get back is from the `MediaStore` or otherwise has a `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA` column. Not only do camera apps not have to return a `Uri`, but there is no requirement that the `Uri` is from the `MediaStore` or have such a column.

Comment: See now I have updated my code i am not using if else .. I posted wrong sorry

Comment: What should i pass in putExtra along with EXTRA OUTPUT ? @CommonsWare

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal: Ideally, use a `Uri` that is backed by a `ContentProvider`. You can use a `file:` `Uri`, but that will not work on Android 7.0+ with a `targetSdkVersion` of 24+. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) for an example.

Comment: Can you please explain more . Simply i want to get path of image i captured . Rest i know how to get thumbnail if path is known.

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal: "Simply i want to get path of image i captured" -- then you have to provide a `Uri` that you would like the camera app to use, via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath), [books](https://commonsware.com/Android), etc. However, do bear in mind that [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not reliable](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html), because camera app developers seem to not test it very much.

Comment: You mean i have to provide uri with put extra  . Ok . So i have to pre define path where image will be saved , pre define title of image , like given in other answers of same question types. ? Am i right ?

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal: Images do not have titles, so I do not know what you mean by "pre define title of image". But, yes, if you want full-size images, you need to tell the camera app where you want it to write the image, by providing a writeable `Uri` to that location via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123830/discussion-between-karandeep-atwal-and-commonsware).

Comment: thanx alot its working now , I pass Uri uri in `putExtra` and in `onActivityResult` i get path by `uri.getPath();` 
Now a Question is arising in my mind .As u said earlier My app can crash on well written Camera App. Should i pass URI in Video Capturing too? although its working fine by `data.getData()` in all devices i tested . Should I tell Camera app where to save Video or continue using `data.getData();`. ?

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal: "Should i pass URI in Video Capturing too?" -- there you have your choice, according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE). You can use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` if you want, or skip it if you do not want and use the returned `Uri`.

Comment: " If you want a full-size image, use EXTRA_OUTPUT on your Intent, in which case you know where the image is being stored — it is wherever you are indicating in EXTRA_OUTPUT.". You only wrote that the op is doing the wrong way. There is no answer (or no code).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Uri from Bitmap so

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context applicationContext, Bitmap bitmapImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), bitmapImage, "Some Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode==CAPTURE_IMAGE_CODE){

                Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                //ImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

                Uri inputImageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),bitmapImage); 
            }
        }
    }
```

And add call this onClick

```
private void takeImage(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CODE);
        }

    }
```