# App Crashing because URI give NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, uri

am developing an app to upload images to my server via gallery and camera My problem is I get a NullPointerException on some of my code and I have NO idea of how to fix this. the error occurs in my activity that calls the camera and uploads the image Other Questions on SO didn't help me

According to the log, it is this line

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

as well as

```
photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

the log also gives the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.smartpractice.myapplication/com.smartpractice.myapplication.CameraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
```

Attaching the code now

Camera Activity

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

Button btpic, btnup;
private Uri fileUri;
String picturePath;
Uri selectedImage;
Bitmap photo;
String ba1;
public static String URL = "https://www.smartpractice.co.za/files-upload-ruben.asp?MyForm=Yes";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    btpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cpic);
    btpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickpic();
        }
    });

    btnup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
    btnup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            upload();
        }
    });
}

private void upload() {
    // Image location URL
    Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);

    // Image
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

    // Upload image to server
    new uploadToServer().execute();

}

private void clickpic() {
    // Check Camera
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // Open default camera
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Camera not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Error occurs here**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        selectedImage = data.getData();
        **photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");**

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            **cursor.moveToFirst();**

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageView =findViewById(R.id.Imageprev);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonOne=findViewById(R.id.activity2btn);
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent activity2Intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity2Intent);
        }
    });

            Button buttonTwo=findViewById(R.id.activity2btn2);
            buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Intent activity2Intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadActivity.class);
                    startActivity(activity2Intent);



        }
    });
}
```

}

**MANIFEST**

```
fest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.smartpractice.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".TimeLogActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".CameraActivity"
            />
        <activity android:name=".UploadActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="andriod.intent.action.main"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After the button click, it must send me to the activity from there it opens the camera

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camera activity returning null android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982184/camera-activity-returning-null-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all the `Cursor` stuff. There is not supposed to be a `Uri` returned by `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. And, even if there were a `Uri`, there is no requirement for the `MediaStore` to know about it, and the `DATA` column is no longer available on Android Q and higher.

Your image will be the thumbnail `Bitmap` from `data.getExtras().get("data");`.

Alternatively, provide your own `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (instead of the `null` that you are providing now), so you control where the image should be stored. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Camera/FileProvider) shows how to use `FileProvider` with `EXTRA_OUTPUT` for this purpose.

Comment: That solved the problem of it crashing and nullpointer BUT now after the thumbnaail is displayed and I click Upload it crashes completely

Comment: @RubenMeiring: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace of the crash. If you cannot interpret the cause of the crash, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with your now-current code and the complete stack trace.